# How do you split an A3 document into two A4 columns with page numbering for both columns in LaTex Overleaf?

Tags: latex

We are required to format our report in landscape orientation on A3 paper. We need to split that A3 paper into two A4 columns. In essence, as if you are reading a book/booklet. The code that I'm using below has an issue. The issue is the page numbering still counts per A3 page and not per column. If anyone could me a hand with this, would be much appreciated! Thanks.

```
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\begin{document} 

\begin{multicols}{2}

%Inserted test here 

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of columns, it might be easier to just put two A4 pages on an A3 page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}% just to get some dummy content

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a3paper,landscape]

\begin{document}

\duckument % just to get some dummy content

\end{document}
```